# Webcomic about a teenager who joins a group of evil minions because his criminal record means he can't get regular work

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

At the start of the story, the teenager steals a diamond ring for a girl he knows, but gets caught because his tactic basically consisted of having his friend distract the sales clerk, smashing the case, and grabbing the ring. After serving some time, he finds that the fact that he has a felony on his record means he can't get most work, so he and a friend (I believe the main character is fairly skinny and his friend portly) join up as professional minions for an evil overlord.

I think I read this somewhere in early 2000, in English, but I'm really not certain. The first set of minion armor was either blue or purple, and he got access to some advanced weaponry. At first, things look like it's going to be strictly comedy, about how incompetent the minions are and how the cartoonish the overlords are, but then people start dying, making the kids realize just how serious the situation is that they got into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it (sort of). It was *[Minion](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/MinionComics)* by "[Minion Comics](https://www.minioncomics.com/?p=5)".

> The comic is about two unemployed losers who take jobs as henchmen with an evil organization, after one of them, Spencer, gets convicted of theft and is unable to find a job. The organization is ostensibly dedicated to promoting freedom of information by hacking into government and corporate secret files.

The reason it was so difficult to find was a combination of the generic name and that [the website](https://www.minionwebcomic.com/) seems to be defunct although [the Wayback Machine can get to some of the pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20130818142052/http://www.minionwebcomic.com/index.php?id=1).

I spoke to the author. The site (as well as that of another of their comics) was hacked and they have not been able to contact the hosting company to recover it. He sent me a copy of the strips as a CBZ archive and I read through the entirety of it.